# Two Nginx Reverse Proxies Behind each other with SSL

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to set up two reverse proxies behind each other. Here is a little sketch of my network:

[Home Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4O9Y.png)

So i want to run one nginx reverse proxy on my Ubuntu Server and one on my Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi has no service running on it 24/7, because it is for testing purposes or temporary services only.

[Reverse Proxies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtN3.png)

The following picture shows how i want to use the SSL-Certificates and where I want to issue them. I want to issue the certificates for the services running on my Ubuntu Server in my Ubuntu Server and I want to issue the SSL Certificates for the services running on my Rasperry Pi in my Raspberry Pi.

[SSL-Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C75fF.png)

My problem is, that issuing the SSL Certificate (with Certbot on my Raspberry Pi) was successfull, but when I want to access the HTTPS-Service running on my Raspberry Pi now, the Nginx Reverse Proxy running on my Ubuntu Server doesn't forward all traffic to the Nginx Reverse Proxy on my Raspberry Pi and it uses a Certificate installed on my Ubuntu Server.

Here is the Nginx configuration of the Ubuntu Server:

```
server {
    server_name raspberry.mydomain.tld www.raspberry.mydomain.tld;

    ssl off;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://192.168.0.45:443;
    }
}
```

And here is the Nginx configuration of the Raspberry Pi:

```
server {
    server_name raspberry.mydomain.tld www.raspberry.mydomain.tld;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/raspberry.mydomain.tld/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/raspberry.mydomain.tld/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = www.raspberry.mydomain.tld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = raspberry.mydomain.tld) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen         80 default_server;
    server_name raspberry.mydomain.tld www.raspberry.mydomain.tld;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I think this behaviour arises because of the Nginx configuration on my Ubuntu Server, but I don't know. Please Help me!

Thank You!

Bananenkönig

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not set HTTPS listener and valid certificate on Ubuntu server, because you are trying to terminate HTTPS on it and then proxy pass that requests to Raspberry Pi.

So you need to specify certificate in the nginx setup to be able to proxy pass HTTPS traffic.

And also please note, if you want to proxy pass HTTPS traffic, then an upstream should also be configured to accept HTTPS connections.

Add HTTPS listener and certificate settings to your config at Ubuntu server in server section.

```
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate     /path_to_cert/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path_to_key/server.key;
```

Remove `ssl off;`

Add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` line to location:

```
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://192.168.0.45:443;
    }
```

I recommend you to configure and issue SSL certificates only on Ubuntu Server and then proxy pass only http traffic to Raspberry Pi to eliminate unnecessary overheads.

Comment: So it is impossible to forward all the traffic from the Ubuntu Server to the Raspberry Pi without installing a Certificate on my Ubuntu Server?

I know that this is a lot of overhead, but as I mentioned this Raspberry Pi is for testing purposes only.